Flutter Pub Login Issue with IDX Service: Unable to Authenticate
I am encountering an issue while trying to log in using flutter pub with an IDX Google.It ask me to click the link to authenticate, when i follow the steps, it will lead me to a localhost url when click on the url...
enter image description here
I have tried many time, but it will lead me to this url. I want to publish via idx google.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

i have the same problem too.
